# Creating Alias to `man` with arguments -online?

Tags: powershell

I want to create an alias for `Get-Help [foo] -online`. But I can't get arguments to work.

I tried a few things including `Set-Alias -Name mano -Value "Get-Help -online"`

```
PS C:\Program Files\ConEmu> mano Get-Content
Cannot resolve alias 'mano' because it refers to term 'Get-Help -online',
which is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, operable program, or script
 file. Verify the term and try again.
At line:1 char:5
+ mano <<<<  Get-Content
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mano:String) [], CommandNo
   tFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AliasNotResolvedException
```

Comment: As much as everyone would like it, powershell is not bash... still possible though! (see my answer)  There may be a better way of doing this though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't create an alias with arguments like that.

You can use a function though. Something like...

```
PS> function mano { Get-Help $args[0] -online }
```

If you want this to be available every time you start ps, then you can put it in your profile. see `$profile`.

Comment: I get AliasNotResolved ( because it refers to the term `Get-Help -online` which is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, operable program, or script file.

Comment: @monkey I updated it. You shouldn't have been getting the error you just described, because I wasn't using an alias. But it did need to specify args[0] rather than the array $args

Answer (score 5):

If you have Powershell v3

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{
    "Get-Help:Online" = {$True}
}
```